# Assigning datasets to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I am generating a set of 6 datasets per pass  through a loop that iterates over 4 years (2011,2013,2015,2017), so that I will have a total of 24 datasets. I am trying to concatenate the name of each dataset with the corresponding year using assign-paste.
However, I am only getting 6 datasets at the end of the loop instead of 6*4 =24.

Do I need a special [[]] syntax for creating the list of data frames? Why am I not able to assign datasets to variables inside the loop structure below?

```
library(educationdata)
library(glue)

## Initialize lists
dates<-list("2011","2013","2015","2017")
frames<-list("df_ccdirectory","df_ccdenrollment","df_crdcteacher",
             "df_crdcmathscience","df_crdcsat","df_crdcfinance")
dflist <- list()



  for (j in dates){
    
    df_ccdirectory <- get_education_data(level = "schools",
                                source = "ccd",
                                topic = "directory",
                                filters = list(year = j,fips=10),
                                add_labels = TRUE)
    dflist[[1]]<- df_ccdirectory

    df_ccdenrollment <- get_education_data(level = "schools",
                                      source = "ccd",
                                      topic = "enrollment",
                                      filters = list(year = j,fips=10),
                                      add_labels = TRUE)
    dflist[[2]]<-   df_ccdenrollment
    df_crdcteacher<- get_education_data(level = "schools",
                           source = "crdc",
                           topic = "teachers-staff",
                           filters = list(year = j,fips=10),
                           add_labels = TRUE)
    dflist[[3]]<-    df_crdcteacher
    df_crdcmathscience <- get_education_data(level = "schools",
                                         source = "crdc",
                                         topic = "math-and-science",
                                         subtopic = c('race','sex'),
                                         filters = list(year = j,fips=10),
                                         add_labels = TRUE)
    dflist[[4]]<- df_crdcmathscience

    df_crdcsat <- get_education_data(level = "schools",
                           source = "crdc",
                           topic = "sat-act-participation",
                           subtopic = c('race','sex'),
                           filters = list(year = j,fips=10),
                           add_labels = TRUE)
    dflist[[5]] <-df_crdcsat

    df_crdcfinance <- get_education_data(level = "schools",
                                     source = "crdc",
                                     topic = "school-finance",
                                     filters = list(year = j,fips=10),
                                     add_labels = TRUE)
    dflist[[6]]<-df_crdcfinance

    
  
    ## Error catching...
    #print(dates[[j]],"\n")
    print(paste0("dataset 1"))
    cat("\n")
        head(dflist[[1]])
    cat("\n")
    print(paste0("dataset 6"))
    cat("\n")
    head(dflist[[6]])
    cat("\n")
    for (k in 1:6){
        assign(paste(frames[k], dates[j], sep = ""), dflist[[k]])
  
    }
  
 
 }
```

Comment: Changed the code , so outer loop iterated over years. Still doesn't work? Are the indices still off?

Comment: Yes, when you write `dflist[[1]]` in the first iteration of the loop, it writes to the first element of `dflist`. The second time round it just overwrites it. Maybe try changing all your `dflist[[1]]`, `dflist[[2]]` etc to `dflist[[length(dflist) + 1]]`. That way, you always write to the end of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider several adjustments:

1. Continue using a *single* data frame list and avoid flooding your global environment with many separate, similarly structured data. For debugging and side effect issues, `assign` should rarely be used in R. Instead, assign names to your data frame list.
2. Avoid the bookkeeping of `for` loops with the more streamlined *apply* family methods that hides the loop and returns collections and with some cases, as shown below with `sapply`, named collections. Also, `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) is the elementwise member of family.
3. Keep your code DRY (**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself) by parameterizing the `get_education_data` call which differ between the six by *source* and *topic* parameters.

Adjusted code

```r
# USER-DEFINED PARAMETERIZED METHOD
build_df <- function(year_param, source_param, topic_param) {
    get_education_data(
        level = "schools",
        source = source_param,
        topic = topic_param,
        filters = list(year = year_param, fips=10),
        add_labels = TRUE
    )
}

# INITIALIZE VECTORS
dates <- c("2011", "2013", "2015", "2017")
sources <- c("ccd", "ccd", "crdc", "crdc", "crdc", "crdc")
topics <- c(
    "directory", "enrollment", "teachers-staff",
    "math-and-science", "sat-act-participation",
    "school-finance"
)
frames <- c(
    "df_ccdirectory", "df_ccdenrollment", "df_crdcteacher",
    "df_crdcmathscience", "df_crdcsat", "df_crdcfinance"
)

# RETURN NESTED YEARLY LIST OF DATA FRAMES
df_list <- sapply(
    dates, 
    function(dt) setNames(Map(build_df, dt, sources, topics), frames),
    simplify = FALSE
)
```

**Output**

```r
# ALL DATA FRAMES (N=24)
df_list$`2011`$df_ccdirectory
df_list$`2011`$df_ccdenrollment
...
df_list$`2017`$df_crdcsat
df_list$`2017`$df_crdcfinance


# ALL 2011 DATA FRAMES (N=6)
df_list$`2011`


# ALL ccdirectory DATA FRAMES (N=4)
lapply(df_list, `[[`, "df_ccdirectory")
```

Comment: Thanks, not only for the specific solution, but also particularly for the broad code suggestions you made at the beginning - these sound like very good principles in all situations.

Comment: Excellent! Great to hear and glad to help. Happy coding!